# Reducing annotation parameters

Tags: java

First of all, this is more out of curiosity and the only benefit for it will be a cleaner looking code.

I have an Entity representing one of my DB tables. On it, I have one `@NamedQuery` and one `@NamedNativeQuery` (With the corresponding `@SqlResultSetMapping` for the former).

This works. Nothing wrong about it. The "problem" is how overloaded it seems.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "objects")
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "MyObject.getObjectPreview",   
                  query = "SELECT " + 
                           "    o.attr AS attr1, a.attr AS attr2, b.attr AS attr3 " + 
                           "FROM objects o " + 
                           "   LEFT JOIN related1 a ON a.id = o.id_related1 " + 
                           "   LEFT JOIN related2 b ON b.id = o.id_related2 " + 
                           "WHERE o.id_objeto = ?1",
                  resultSetMapping = "Mapping.MyObjectPreview")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "Mapping.MyObjectPreview",
                    classes = @ConstructorResult(targetClass = ObjectPreview.class,
                                                 columns = {@ColumnResult(name = "attr1"), 
                                                            @ColumnResult(name = "attr2"),
                                                            @ColumnResult(name = "attr3")}))
public class MyObject implements Serializable {

    /*Attributes, getters, setters and such*/

}
```

So, to make this a bit more 'readable', I started by putting my Query in a different class and access it through a static method. The next step, and what bring the question, is about doing the same, but with `classes` of the `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation.

Ideally, I'd like it to externalize as much as possible. In this example I use annotation for individual queries and mapping, but the goal would be to externalize all of them. So it'd go from (example only)

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "objects")
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "MyObject.getObjectPreview", query = NamedQueries.GET_OBJECT_PREVIEW,
                  resultSetMapping = "Mapping.MyObjectPreview")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "Mapping.MyObjectPreview", classes = QueryingConstuctors.OBJECT_PREVIEW)
public class MyObject implements Serializable {

    /*Attributes, getters, setters and such*/

}
```

to

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "objects")
@NamedNativeQueries(value = NativeQueries.OBJECT_ENTITY)
@SqlResultSetMappings(value = QueryingConstructors.OBJECT_MAPPINGS)
public class MyObject implements Serializable {

    /*Attributes, getters, setters and such*/

}
```

Again, I only expect less clutter near the beginning of this class. I'm also aware that functionality like this could be achieved with constructor expressions, but they are not available in the JPA version I need to work with.

Main problems I'm facing are, obviously, about "returning" an interface without implementation, so I can't just `return @SqlResultSetMapping( /*args*/ );`. Another option I tried is to aggregate annotations, but that resulted in either "no property found" for my query or "invalid query" if I excluded `@NamednativeQueries`. My final idea is to make an abstract class, put all my annotations there and still annotate MyObject with `@Entity`, but that is a more delicate move as this class is one of the most important classes in this system and I'm trying to be as unobtrusive as possible.

Is this achievable at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Spring support Xml configuration. So instead of setting your config as annotations, you could create a completely separate Xml file which does the same job.

Comment: That's the orm.xml file, right? Our project doesn't have one (Those who started it settled on all Java config). I'm guessing adding one even this late shouldn't be an issue, but I would like to stick to Java, for consistency sake. I'll try it but I don't know if I'll leave it. Thank you!